# PHP bringing in XML from URL

Tags: javascript, php, xml

thanks for your time.
I'm working on my homework project that's based on Google Developer's: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#outputxml.  Basically I'm pulling xml content from a URL using php and then reading it in an html file using javascript.  Fun stuff right?  I've never written php before so I'm not sure I'm coding it correctly.  Below is my PHP:

```
<?php

// Get parameters from URL - PHP accepting 2 variables from index.html
$address = $_GET["address"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

// Start XML file
$dom = new \DOMDocument("1.0");

header("Content-type: text/xml");

$dom = file_get_contents('http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/stores(area(' + $address + ',' + $radius + '))?show=name,address,distance,lat,lng&apiKey=fuzgmrj4nv8v9ummatn78m3k');
file_put_contents('file.xml', $dom);

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

This is the Javascript that is reading the php generated xml:

```
function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     clearLocations();

    var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
     var searchUrl = 'phpGenXML.php?address=' + address + '&radius=' + radius;
     downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
       var xml = parseXml(data);
       var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

       //Create markers
       for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
         var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
         var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
         var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

         createOption(name, distance, i);
         createMarker(latlng, name, address);
         bounds.extend(latlng);
       }
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
       locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
       locationSelect.onchange = function() {
         var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
       };
      });
    }
```

So I'm worried that I'm doing something wrong while pulling in the XML.  Can anyone tell me if it looks alright?

Thanks,
Tommy

Comment: [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for this

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code does have several errors:

- Concatenation in PHP is done with a `.` rather than `+`.
- You're creating an instance of `DOMDocument`, then re-assigning to the variable. `$dom` then becomes a string, which you're trying to call `saveXML()` on, which will produce an error.
- `file_put_contents()` doesn't do what you think it does. Have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/file_put_contents).

Try this instead:

```
$address = $_GET['address'];
$radius = $_GET['radius'];

// sanitise $address and $radius

header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo file_get_contents('http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/stores(area(' . $address . ',' . $radius . '))?show=name,address,distance,lat,lng&apiKey=fuzgmrj4nv8v9ummatn78m3k');
```